# Blaze-Apollo w/ Meteor, observer not triggering the subscribe on variable change

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to re-fetch the data on variable change from blaze-apollo using graphql query.

The query is :

```
this.rows = this.gqlQuery({
    query: GET_DATA,
    variables: {
        databaseId: dbId,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        limit: 2
    },
    fetchPolicy: "network-only"
});
```

The subscriber is :

```
 this.rowsObservableSub = this.rows.observer.subscribe({
    next: ({ loading }) => {
        console.log("loading is ===> ", loading);
    }
});
```

and the observer is called as:

```
this.autorun(()=> {
    if(this.searchTerm.get()){
        const variables = {
            databaseId: dbId,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            limit: 4
        };
        this.rows.observer.setVariables(variables);
    }
});
```

`this.rowObservableSub` is not triggered on the change in `variable` when `searchTerm` changes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, the following changes tell the observer to persist with the `network-only` fetchPolicy instead of hitting the `cache`

`this.rows.observer.setVariables(variables, true)`